# Super Privilege required for running scheduled events?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I want to run scheduled events on cloud sql but it requires **GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON**; and per [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-privileges.html) requires super privilege, and afaik cloud sql doesn't support them and understandably I see this when I run the above:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

My question is if there is an alternative here or am I complete screwed relying on cloud sql ?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cloud Console to edit your instance and enable the `event_scheduler` flag under `Advanced Options`:

[image: advanced options]

Comment: thanks again @Vadim, this is a life saver, I also feel dumb not digging into the console.